# How to compile MacVim under OS X Yosemite, or where can I download MacVim with GUI support?

Tags: user-interface, compilation, macvim, application-error

Where can I download MacVim with GUI, or why OS X compile instructions don't work?

I googled both questions and can't seem to find a reasonable answer to either one, so I would rather ask than waste my time trying to figure it out myself.

I tried to compile MacVim under OS X 10.10.2 but when I install the resulting MacVim.app and try to run it, I get error message box that says "MacVim.app" can't open application damaged or incomplete".  I followed the instruction in the INSTALLmac.txt, which are simple:

make
make test
sudo make install

The app is copied to /Applications in last step but as I said, it doesn't work.

I actually just want to install MacVim with GUI, not necessarily compile it. However, when I install latest precompiled app (v8.0.1157) from the recommended page http://macvim-dev.github.io/macvim/ it doesn't seem to support GUI.

The README file on Github's project page simply states that MacVim also comes with GUI, but it doesn't elaborate on how to get that version or how to enable GUI, which by the way seems like a bad practice to me.

Answer (score 0):

I found **VimBox** last nite which was developed by Jordan W (https://github.com/jordwalke) and other contributors. I guess that's just one way to quickly configure MacVim to support GUI and give it much prettier interface. It's fast to set up and run and it is exactly what I was after:

https://github.com/jordwalke/VimBox

I also slightly modified my ***/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/mvim*** file and added **alias v='/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/mvim'** to my .bashrc so that now I can just type `v some_file.php` to edit it MacVim.

I think that's all I did, I hope it helps someone quickly configure MacVim with the nice interface you see in some video tutorials but don't quite know how to get there. Let me know if you have any questions and I will help if I can.

Ah, I also installed few new cool fonts with ligatures, they are all free and are compatibe with MacVim:

```
Fira Code
Monoid
Iosevka (I like this one)
Insonsolata for Powerline
```

Use the one you like, or search for more free fonts.